Proving the equivalence of two infinite series of floor functions
Prove for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor \sqrt{\frac{n}{k^3}} \right\rfloor = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor \sqrt[3]{\frac{n}{k^2}} \right\rfloor$$
Let the left sum be $A$, and other be $B$. Both sequences converge to zero, so only terms with $n>k^3$ and $n>k^2$ matter for $A$ and $B$ respectively. But even if I can define how many terms contribute to the final sum, how would I prove their respective floor of square and cube roots will amount to the same value? The alternating squares and cubes causes so much overlap within the patterns that there's no recurring relation to use.

Hint: $\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor = \sum\limits_{i\in \left{1,2,3,\ldots\right};\ i\leq x} 1$ for any nonnegative real $x$.

Consider the sets $M = \{(k,l)\in \mathbb N^2\mid l\leq \sqrt{\frac{n}{k^3}}\}$ and $N = \{(k,l)\in \mathbb N^2\mid l\leq \sqrt[3]{\frac{n}{k^2}}\}$. Notice that $\forall (k,l)\in \mathbb N^2, (k,l)\in M \Longleftrightarrow k^3l^2\leq n \Longleftrightarrow (l,k)\in N$. Thus $|M| = |N|$ as the two sets are in bijection (an explicit bijection would be $f:((k,l)\in M)\mapsto (l,k)\in N$).
All that's left to do is to notice that since $\forall x\in \mathbb R^+, \lfloor x\rfloor = \sum_{i\in \mathbb N, i\leq x}1$, We find that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor \sqrt{\frac{n}{k^3}} \right\rfloor = |M| = |N| =  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor \sqrt[3]{\frac{n}{k^2}} \right\rfloor.$$
